# Render a string via Mathjax

Tags: mathjax

I have an text area that where I expect the user to enter the mathematical expression. I wan't to render any results immediately, just like it works here on SO.
Something like:

```
<div id="preview"></div>

function onkeyup(event) {
    var prev = document.getElementById("preview");
    Using just a HTML string:
    prev.innerHTML = MathJax.renderString(this.value);

    ... or get DOM object tree instead:
    //Remove previous children
    prev.innerHTML = "";
    //Append new DOM tree
    var tree = MathJax.createDOM(this.value);
    prev.appendChild(tree);
}
```

Is that possible? Or will I have to put `this.value` in some div element and than have MathJax parse that element? (that would be stupid)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The task you are trying to perform is documented [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/advanced/typeset.html#manipulating-individual-math-elements), and there is a live example [here](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic.html).

Basically, the method is to use

```
<div id="preview">\(\)</div>
```

and then typeset the preview.  Once that completes, use the `getAllJax()` method to get the empty math element jax.  Something like

```
var jax;
MathJax.Hub.Queue(
  ["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"preview"],
  function () {jax = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("preview")[0]}
);
```

Then use the element jax's `Text()` method to change the math that it displays.

```
function onkeyup(event) {
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Text",jax,this.value]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you please give me any leads on how to do this dynamically?

Comment: Did you look at the two links that I included in the first sentence?  The first is to the documentation, and the second is to a live example whose code you could view.

Comment: The link to the documentation is invalid as of now, 2 Apr 2018

Comment: This is not obvious (to me at least).  Fortunately it looks like more intuitive wrapper functions will be provided in version 3, in beta as of this post.  There is a section on this in the docs [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html).